# Angular2 How to Define Input Property in Plain JS

Tags: angular

I want to specify an Input property for my component using plain JS (not typescript).

The only documentation I can find is this (which is from the Angular2 [cheat sheet](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html)):

```
ng.core.Input(myProperty, myComponent); 
//Declares an input property that we can 
//update via property binding (e.g. <my-cmp [my-property]="someExpression">).
```

I've tried this in my component's constructor:

```
.Class({
   constructor: function () {    
       ng.core.Input(this.name, this);        
   }
});
```

However, it does not work (no errors are reported either).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For these cases you have `inputs` and `outputs` properties. Note that for the TS case the annotations are singular (`Input` and `Output`) and with plain JS they're plural (`inputs` and `outputs`).

```js
var Children = ng.core.
  Component({
    inputs : ['myValue'], // Equivalent to @Input('myValue')
    outputs : ['emitValue'] // Equivalent to @Output() emitValue;
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: function() {
      // Initialize emitValue
      this.emitValue = new ng.core.EventEmitter();
    },

    // Available at ngOnInit lifecycle
    ngOnInit : function() { 
      console.log(this.myValue);
    },

    // Value that the component will emit
    emit : function() {
      this.emitValue.emit('This is some value from children');
    }
  });
```

With `inputs` you can use the syntax `[internalValue: externalValue]`, which basically would give you the possibility to do this

```js
<another-cmp [externalValue]="someExpression"></another-cmp>

.Component({
  inputs : ['internalValue: externalValue']
})
.Class({
  ngOnInit : function() {

    // 'internalValue' contains 'externalValue' value
    console.log(this.internalValue); 
  }
})
```

And for the parent component

```js
var Parent = ng.core.
    Component({
        selector: 'cmp',
        template : `
            <another-cmp [myValue]="myValue" (emitValue)="printValue($event)">
            </another-cmp>
            What does my children have to say? {{childrenValue}}
        `,
        directives : [Children]
    }).
    Class({
        constructor: function() {
            this.myValue = 'Some value to pass to children';
        },
        printValue : function(value) {
            this.childrenValue = value;
        }
});
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ire44Wk3z3GL3pJtFVO?p=preview) demonstrating the case. I hope it helps.

Comment: Works perfectly, great explanation!

Comment: great! thank you! Wonder to know where do you get this info, if there's no docs for JS.

Comment: Hmm.. I can't get it to work and the Plunker example throws "EXCEPTION: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in Chromium 53. I'm trying to adapt https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html to ES2015

Comment: OK, I got it working locally. I tried to create a new Plunker with what I got but am getting reference error for System and ng from the angular2.js snap shot. http://plnkr.co/edit/HDFMFgiGBdgHbnS2KQoA?p=preview

Comment: Finally figured out which dependencies that is needed to run Angular2 (the snap shot version didn't work for me). http://plnkr.co/edit/HDFMFgiGBdgHbnS2KQoA?p=preview